# Why Vi(on) minimum values is higher than the typical value of PDTC124E (NPN transistor)?

Tags: transistors

Please see the [datasheet of PDTC124E](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PDTC124E_SER.pdf) (NPN transistor) for reference.

I have added the snapshot of relevant section for quick reference.

**Snapshot**
[image]

Here the Vi(on) value for the transistor is 2.5V and 1.7V are minimum and typical values respectively.

Please explain why typical value is less than the minimum value.

I am a beginner in analog filed. Apologies in advance if the question is very basic.

Thanks,

VT

Comment: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PDTC124E_SER.pdf, Here is the datasheet I have missed to attach in the query.

Comment: You can just edit the question, did that for you already.

Answer (score 2):

*Vi(on) value for the transistor is 2.5V and 1.7V are minimum and typical values respectively.*

This is just a choice NXP made in representing the data. In this case you could also read the minimum value as the *worst case* value.

Since this specification point is "the minimum voltage you need to turn the transistor on while having Ic = 5 mA and having a Vce of 0.3 V".

As a designer what I need to know is: "What is the minimum (smallest) voltage that I would need to turn this transistor on under these conditions ?" That minimum is 2.5 V, as long as I apply 2.5 V **or more** (that is why 2.5 V is a minimum !) the transistor will be on.

In practice a typical transistor will only need 1.7 V but NXP will not guarantee that all these transistors behave in a "typical" way. So they specify that you need at least 2.5 V so that even the most stubborn transistor will turn on. NXP might test that they all work at 2.5 V and scrap the ones which do not turn on even at 2.5 V.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels/ttl-logic-levels

This is because you invert the order of the "logic". 
One signal that it is upper the 1.7 V will be considered as a "1" logic, so you need less voltage to your range that in the case that you will have 2.5 V.

The minimum is 2.5 V because you need more than 2.5 V to have a "1" logic.

Comment: what do you mean by invert the order of the "logic"?